# Run unit tests for two Django applications in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I've Django project with two applications with added unit tests (django.test.TestCase). In PyCharm I have created two Django test launchers (one for every app). In this configuration everything works correctly. Now I want to create one test launcher, which will be able to start unit test for both applications at once.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found solution.

If you want to launch many test suits with one test launcher in PyCharm, you should add names of your applications separated by a space to Target field of your Django tests Run/Debug configuration.